# Establishing OpenVPN connection only works on the 2nd try

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I'm running a debian-server with OpenVPN and I'm trying to establish a connection to it over the internet (windows client). However I've noticed that it always takes a long time, since it seems to hit the timeout.

I always get to this part:

```
MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1561445206,WAIT
```

at the end of the timeout, I get this:

```
TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
```

HOWEVER, then my client tries to connect again (after 5 seconds) and it immediately establishes the connection.

```
SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1561445266,RECONNECTING,tls-error,,,,,
Restart pause, 5 second(s)
TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]x.x.x.x:x
Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
UDP link local: (not bound)
UDP link remote: [AF_INET]x.x.x.x:x
MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1561445271,WAIT,,,,,,
MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1561445271,AUTH,,,,,,
```

90% of the time it works like this where it only connects on the second try - sometimes it also (seemingly at random) connects on the first try

Answer (score 0):

this is a DNS issue. Check your DNS settings and make sure your OpenVPN server has a valid  FQDN . 
Or ...
Add your OpenVPN server ip to the windows hosts file.

Comment: My OpenVPN server is behind a NAT with port-forwarding via router. My router is also my DNS - so there is nothing to configure. Are you saying the router isn't forwarding the connection properly or isn't doing the DNS properly? All other hosts from within my NAT can access the openVPN machine perfectly fine via hostname